# First two tags only visible in tagged questions page for few tags in stackapps

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, stackapps

There is a strange issue with the [`tampermonkey`](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/tampermonkey), [`firefox`](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/firefox) tags in stackapps.

For sample:

When filtering the **[tampermonkey]** in search box the questions are listed with only the first 2 tags, even though it has more than 2 tags.

Even in the first 2 tags, other than the **tampermonkey** tags only shown.

Added screenshot for future reference:

> [image: Tampermonkey no tag]

Note: Same issue in Chrome, Firefox. Windows 10 OS.

Comment: Seeing the same with greasemonkey, chat and firefox tags. Likely other tags are effected too.

Comment: Related: ["Special" required tag listings only show single required tag](http://stackapps.com/q/2151)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a special post list in StackApps - you will note that app icons are showing up.

If all the posts in the page are applications (app, script, library), you see this view, where up to two tags are displayed - the one chosen by the OP and then the most popular tag in the post (barring mod only and other app tags).

When the post list contains other, non app posts, the view is reverted to the usual question list (no app icon, all tags show etc...).

For some tags, when you move to the next page, you could get a different list view, depending on the types of posts in that page.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of the tag you're searching for, the lists which contain only scripts and apps are shown with only two tags (the required and the least popular one, so as to define the "topic" of script/app narrower), probably in order not to clog up the list - I don't think this is really a bug, but an intentional move.