# Display all tags on the Top Apps and Top Scripts pages

Tags: feature-request, tags, stackapps

Only two tags are visible currently, even when there are more tags. Please display all tags. See the screenshot below:

> [image: screenshot of the Top Apps page]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [First two tags only visible in tagged questions page for few tags in stackapps](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280301/first-two-tags-only-visible-in-tagged-questions-page-for-few-tags-in-stackapps)

Comment: @Arulkumar not a duplicate, that one is a bug report marked as [meta-tag:by-design]. This one is a feature request to change it.